# When using inner join throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have next database model:
[image: db scheme.]

I want will receive selected by category posts list. I recive selected by category programs list as follows:

```
var pre_request = from el in db.programs
                  where el.program_categories.Any(n => n.categories.slug_name == categ)
                  select el.id;
var programCat = pre_request.ToList();
```

It correctly works. In order that receive posts list, i use `INNER JOIN` as follows:

```
var request = (from c in db.posts
               join c2 in programCat on c.program_id equals c2
               orderby c.id descending
               select new ListItem
               {
                Name = c.name,
                Id = c.id,
                Poster = c.images.FirstOrDefault(n => n.type == "post").href,
               }).Skip(0).Take(1);
List<ListItem> content = request.ToList();
```

When i start this application, it returns `NullReferenceException` on line

```
List<ListItem> content = request.ToList();
```

Why returns `NullReferenceException`? How receive selected by category posts list?

Comment: Please read the **stack trace** of the exception to find out _exactly where_ the exception was raised. I could imagine that `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null` for some rows, so accessing `href` could raise that exception.

Comment: Whats the reason for `Skip(0).Take(1)` ?

Comment: Linq queries are notoriously hard to debug. Most likely, `c.images.FirstOrDefault(n => n.type == "post")` is null because there are no images with a type of `"post"`. try `c.images.FirstOrDefault(n => n.type == "post")?.href` instead.

Comment: EF is an ORM, not a replacement for SQL. It's the *ORM*s job to generate joins from the relations between entities. I doubt this code could run even without the NRE - `programCat` is a *list*, not a DbSet,  which means this code can't be converted to SQL. `join c2 in programCat on c.program_id equals c2` is another weird construct. If you wanted to retrieve posts in specific categories you should have used `where programCat.Containes(c2.program_id)`. This would generate a `WHERE ID IN (...)` clause

Comment: It would be a *lot* better though if the entities had proper relations: Post should have a `Program` property. `Program` should have a `ProgramCategory` property. You could write `where post.Program.ProgramCategory.SlugName= categ` to get all posts in a specific category

Comment: @RandRandom It is made for simplification, in the working code variables are used.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't know. The program can belong to several categories. Several programs can belong to one category.
What connect needs to be used to realize such relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the line:

```
Poster = c.images.FirstOrDefault(n => n.type == "post").href,
```

You used `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`, because you thought: "When, there might be no such image, in that case let's use null". If it returns null, then of course you can't get `.href`.

When using LINQ it is good practice to keep stuff IQueryable / IEnumerable as long as possible. Only the last statement should actually materialize your stuff into a List / Dictionary / One object:

```
Poster = c.images.Where(image => image.type == "post")
                 .Select(image => image.href)
                 .FirstOrDefault(),
```